# RxJava Return single, execute completable after

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to accomplish the following: Return some data as single, execute a completable after. The following code does not compile due to single.andThen(). The actions need to be executed in this order.

```
val single = Single.create<String> { it.onSuccess("result") }
val completable = Completable.create { println("executing cleanup") }
val together = single.andThen(completable)

together.subscribe(
        { println(it) },
        { println(it) }

)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
single.flatMap(v -> completable.andThen(Single.just(v)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you actually want to return the Single *after* the Completable, here's another way:

Using Java:

```
single.flatMap(x -> completable.toSingleDefault(x))
```

Using Kotlin:

```
single.flatMap { completable.toSingleDefault(it) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you don't care whether the result is Single or Completable there is a special `flatMapCompletable` operator in RxJava2 to execute completable after Single:

`single.flatMapCompletable(result -> completable);`

Comment: Simple and elegant tnx

Comment: This returns a `Completable`. The initial question wants it to return a `Single`.

Comment: @DouglasKazumi will this work? `val together = single.flatMap { result -> completable.andThen(Single.just(result)) }`

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina yes! That's exactly what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589752/4266287) proposes. I like [this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701608/4266287) better.

Comment: @DouglasKazumi Ok, you are right :) My answer is incorrect when you do care about the return type (Single). Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a the RxSwift solution:

```
saveObjectsA().flatMap { (objectsA: [A]) -> Single<Bool> in
        B.objects = objectsA
        return completable.andThen(Single.just(true))
    }
```

saveObjectsA returns a Single<[A]> which is an attribute of B (created previously). I needed to save it before saving B.