# RxJava execute Completable after Single asynchronously

Tags: java, rx-java2, rx-android

Is there a way to let a `Single` emit data and when it does (or maybe when it completes) fire a `Completable` with that data in an asynchronous way?

My question is pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48589658/9702840), but I'm trying to call the `Completable` asynchronously.

Here's a trivial example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Single.just("abc")
     .map(string -> {
         myHeavyCompletable(string); //this should be async
         return string;
     });

[...]

private Completable myHeavyCompletable(String string) {
    //heavy logic that could slow down the execution
}
```

I saw that subscribing to the  `Completable` inside the `map` allowed me to somehow accomplish this, but then I wouldn't know how to dispose it in a proper way (as this method is not called inside an activity).

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `flatMapCompletable` and `subscribe` asynchronously on proper thread. This approach combines all the logic as a pipelined sequence, if it isn't what you want you may subscribe your Completables in map and return the disposable as result and collect them at the end and dispose as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I need to return the Single with the data as I'm using that snippet inside a ```Single.concatArrayEager()``` alongside another ```Single``` to concat the results, so I can't return a ```Completable``` or a ```Disposable```

Comment: convert the completable to a single through its method

Comment: If I converted the ```Completable``` to a ```Single``` though I'd lose reference to the data being emitted and the Completable would just be executed synchronously